# Multiple iPhone applications in single code base

Tags: iphone

Can I have multiple iPhone applications in a single Xcode project? If so, will it be an issue during app submission? I need to maintain a minimum of 3 different applications in the same Xcode project. Images and version details will be different. But business logic will be almost similar. Is it possible in Xcode and iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Projects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH5-SW1)

> An Xcode project is a repository for all the files, resources, and
>   information required to build one or more software products. A project
>   contains all the elements used to build your products and maintains
>   the relationships between those elements. It contains one or more
>   targets, which specify how to build products. A project defines
>   default build settings for all the targets in the project (each target
>   can also specify its own build settings, which override the project
>   build settings).

Also on [targets](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH4-SW1), it says

> A target specifies a product to build and contains the instructions
>   for building the product from a set of files in a project or
>   workspace. A target defines a single product; it organizes the inputs
>   into the build system—the source files and instructions for processing
>   those source files—required to build that product. Projects can
>   contain one or more targets, each of which produces one product.

For more details look at [Building and Running Your Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Building/Building.html).